# How to Display Post Method Requests data in Swiftui Ios Simulator Screen?

Tags: api, methods, swiftui

This is Doc File Generate in Postman by write method and url "link/services.php".
This is Header File.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})         @POST("services.php")         
Observable<Division> divisionListApi(@Body HashMap<String, String> map);
map.put("method", "My_List");
```

After Postman Generation I Got This Given Below.

```
{"err_code":9,
"message":"My List ",
"list":[
{"ForestDivision":"Yam(T)"},
{"ForestDivision":"Rewar(T)"},
{"ForestDivision":"Ro(T)"},
{"ForestDivision":"Bh(T)"},
{"ForestDivision":"Ka(T) "},
{"ForestDivision":"Ambal(T) "},
{"ForestDivision":"Fari(T)"}]
}
```

I have made request by taking post mehod, is this the right way to create code in
swiftui.

```
    import Foundation
    import  Combine
    
    struct  File: Decodable, Hashable {
        var error_code : Int
        var message : String
        var list : [lisst]
    }
    
    struct lisst: Decodable, Hashable {
        var ForestDivision: String
    }    
    
    class fetchResults : ObservableObject{
        
        @Published var fetchedRes : [lisst]?
    
    func getData(completion: @escaping (File) -> ()){
        print("Fetch")
    
        let parameters = "{ I dont Know }"
 

       let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: 
 "URl")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData
    
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
            let resultList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(File.self, from: data!)
                            print(" ")
                            print("ID: \(resultList.error_code)")
                            print("VOLUME: \(resultList.message)")
                            print("READINGS: \(String(describing: resultList.list))")
                            print(" ")
            print("SUCCESS: Got data - \(data! )")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       completion(resultList)           // << here !!
                    }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
        
    }
```

Also How to Write in Swiftui View.
To Make Properly Works in List View.

```
    import SwiftUI
    import  UIKit
    
    struct DivisionList: View {    
        @ObservedObject var res = fetchResults()    
        var body: some View {    
            NavigationView {
                Text("Nothing Here")
                
                List(res.fetchedRes ?? [], id: \.self) { resp in      // Error Here
                    ForEach(res.list, id: \.self) { course in
                        VStack {
                            Text(res.for)                             // Error Here
                        }
                    }
                }                       
                .navigationBarTitle("Data")
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        self.getData                                        // Error Here
                    })
            }
    
            }
        }    
    
    struct DivisionList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            DivisionList()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Create New Swift File Copy this Post Requests.  


   
    import Foundation
    import  Combine
    
    let postUrl = "Your URl"
    struct divisionList: Decodable, Identifiable {
      
        
        let id: Int
        let mesg: String
        let list: [FDivision]
        
            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id = "err_code"
                case mesg = "message"
                case list = "list"
            }
        
    }
    
    struct FDivision: Decodable, Hashable {
        let forestDivision: String
        
        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case forestDivision = "ForestDivision"
        
        }
        
        init(data:String) {
            forestDivision = data
        }
        
    }
    
    
    class viewModal: ObservableObject {
        @Published var items = [FDivision]()

    func postData() {
        guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: postUrl) else { return }
        
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                "method": "Your Method Name"

        var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])  else {
            return
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        request.timeoutInterval = 20
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
            session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let response = response {
                    print(response)
                }
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                        if let dictionary = json as? [String:Any] {
                            if let arrList = dictionary["list"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                                for data in arrList{
                                    let model = FDivision(data: data["ForestDivision"] as! String)
                                    self.items.append(model)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        print(json)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
    
                }
            }.resume()
            
            
        }
        
        
    }



 Create Now New Swiftui File. 

 

  import SwiftUI
  import  UIKit


struct DivisionList: View {

@ObservedObject var vm = viewModal()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            
            VStack {
                
               
                List(vm.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text(item.forestDivision).foregroundColor(.customGreen)
                    })
                    
                }
                
                
            }.navigationBarTitle("Data")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                vm.postData()
            })
                    }
                }
            }

struct DivisionList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DivisionList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you have any post method request data,then you want to create some parameter which in given in "fdivision" swift file with url session. And now your post method shown in debug runtime just like fetch data and now if you want to display your data in simulator ios screen then you want to new Swiftui file where you reload your func postdata with the help you can display your data in like List view